# SafariViewController in Guided Access Mode is not working

Tags: swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, guided-access

I am using SafariViewController to open a webpage. It works fine. But due to client requirement, this app need to be in Guided Access Mode. When i put app into Guided Access Mode, then Webpage is not displayed and i am getting below mentioned error in console.

Failed to get remote view controller with error: 
Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={OriginalError=Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"}

Here is code to open SafariViewController

```
func openSafari()
    {

            let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
            self.presentViewController(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            safariVC.delegate = self


    }
```

Please give me some ideas for this issue.

Comment: have you tried using normal web view?

Comment: normal UIwebview is okay. We are planning to explore SafariViewController for future releases